# openstack set quota security group

Tags: openstack

how can I increase the quota of the security group set on Openstack? By default it's set on 10 and for my lab I need more of them. If I try to deploy an App this is the error:

> OverQuotaClient: resources.security_group_host_group_master_3: Quota
>   exceeded for resources: ['security_group_rule'].

Someone know how I can resolve that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution on horzion web UI. Goto:

Projects-> select admin-> Manage Members-> Modify quotas-> Network

here we can modify the quote that are set by default on Openstack.